# How to mock Python static methods and class methods

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

How do I mock a class that has unbound methods?  For example, this class has a `@classmethod` and a `@staticmethod`:

```
class Calculator(object):
    def __init__(self, multiplier):
        self._multiplier = multiplier
    def multiply(self, n):
        return self._multiplier * n
    @classmethod
    def increment(cls, n):
        return n + 1
    @staticmethod
    def decrement(n):
        return n - 1

calculator = Calculator(2)
assert calculator.multiply(3) == 6    
assert calculator.increment(3) == 4
assert calculator.decrement(3) == 2
assert Calculator.increment(3) == 4
assert Calculator.decrement(3) == 2
```

The above pretty much describes my question.  The following is a working example that demonstrates the things I have tried.

Class `Machine` contains an instance of `Calculator`.  I will be testing `Machine` with a mock of `Calculator`.  To demonstrate my issue, `Machine` calls the unbound methods via an instance of `Calculator` and via the `Calculator` class:

```
class Machine(object):
    def __init__(self, calculator):
        self._calculator = calculator
    def mult(self, n):
        return self._calculator.multiply(n)
    def incr_bound(self, n):
        return self._calculator.increment(n)
    def decr_bound(self, n):
        return self._calculator.decrement(n)
    def incr_unbound(self, n):
        return Calculator.increment(n)
    def decr_unbound(self, n):
        return Calculator.decrement(n)

machine = Machine(Calculator(3))
assert machine.mult(3) == 9

assert machine.incr_bound(3) == 4
assert machine.incr_unbound(3) == 4

assert machine.decr_bound(3) == 2
assert machine.decr_unbound(3) == 2
```

All the functional code above works fine.  Next is the part that does not work.

I create a mock of `Calculator` to use in testing `Machine`:

```
from mock import Mock

def MockCalculator(multiplier):
    mock = Mock(spec=Calculator, name='MockCalculator')

    def multiply_proxy(n):
        '''Multiply by 2*multiplier instead so we can see the difference'''
        return 2 * multiplier * n
    mock.multiply = multiply_proxy

    def increment_proxy(n):
        '''Increment by 2 instead of 1 so we can see the difference'''
        return n + 2
    mock.increment = increment_proxy

    def decrement_proxy(n):
        '''Decrement by 2 instead of 1 so we can see the difference'''
        return n - 2
    mock.decrement = decrement_proxy

    return mock
```

In the unit test below, the bound methods use `MockCalculator` as I had hoped.  However, the calls to `Calculator.increment()` and  `Calculator.decrement()` still use `Calculator`:

```
import unittest

class TestMachine(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_bound(self):
        '''The bound methods of Calculator are replaced with MockCalculator'''
        machine = Machine(MockCalculator(3))
        self.assertEqual(machine.mult(3), 18)
        self.assertEqual(machine.incr_bound(3), 5)
        self.assertEqual(machine.decr_bound(3), 1)

    def test_unbound(self):
        '''Machine.incr_unbound() and Machine.decr_unbound() are still using
        Calculator.increment() and Calculator.decrement(n), which is wrong.
        '''
        machine = Machine(MockCalculator(3))
        self.assertEqual(machine.incr_unbound(3), 4)    # I wish this was 5
        self.assertEqual(machine.decr_unbound(3), 2)    # I wish this was 1
```

So I try to patch `Calculator.increment()` and  `Calculator.decrement()`:

```
def MockCalculatorImproved(multiplier):
    mock = Mock(spec=Calculator, name='MockCalculatorImproved')

    def multiply_proxy(n):
        '''Multiply by 2*multiplier instead of multiplier so we can see the difference'''
        return 2 * multiplier * n
    mock.multiply = multiply_proxy
    return mock

def increment_proxy(n):
    '''Increment by 2 instead of 1 so we can see the difference'''
    return n + 2

def decrement_proxy(n):
    '''Decrement by 2 instead of 1 so we can see the difference'''
    return n - 2


from mock import patch

@patch.object(Calculator, 'increment', increment_proxy)
@patch.object(Calculator, 'decrement', decrement_proxy)
class TestMachineImproved(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_bound(self):
        '''The bound methods of Calculator are replaced with MockCalculator'''
        machine = Machine(MockCalculatorImproved(3))
        self.assertEqual(machine.mult(3), 18)
        self.assertEqual(machine.incr_bound(3), 5)
        self.assertEqual(machine.decr_bound(3), 1)

    def test_unbound(self):
        '''machine.incr_unbound() and Machine.decr_unbound() should use
        increment_proxy() and decrement_proxy(n).
        '''
        machine = Machine(MockCalculatorImproved(3))
        self.assertEqual(machine.incr_unbound(3), 5)
        self.assertEqual(machine.decr_unbound(3), 1)
```

Even after patching, the unbound methods want an instance of `Calculator` as an argument:

> TypeError: unbound method increment_proxy() must be called with Calculator instance as first argument (got int instance instead)

How do I mock out class method `Calculator.increment()` and  static method `Calculator.decrement()`?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

C#, Java and C++ programmers tend to overuse class and static methods in Python. The Pythonic approach is to use module functions.

So first, here is the refactored software under test, with methods `increment()` and `decrement()` as module functions.  The interface does change, but the functionality is the same:

```
# Module machines

class Calculator(object):
    def __init__(self, multiplier):
        self._multiplier = multiplier
    def multiply(self, n):
        return self._multiplier * n

def increment(n):
    return n + 1

def decrement(n):
    return n - 1

calculator = Calculator(2)
assert calculator.multiply(3) == 6
assert increment(3) == 4
assert decrement(3) == 2


class Machine(object):
    '''A larger machine that has a calculator.'''
    def __init__(self, calculator):
        self._calculator = calculator
    def mult(self, n):
        return self._calculator.multiply(n)
    def incr(self, n):
        return increment(n)
    def decr(self, n):
        return decrement(n)

machine = Machine(Calculator(3))
assert machine.mult(3) == 9
assert machine.incr(3) == 4
assert machine.decr(3) == 2
```

Add functions `increment_mock()` and `decrement_mock()` to mock `increment()` and `decrement()`:

```
from mock import Mock
import machines

def MockCalculator(multiplier):
    mock = Mock(spec=machines.Calculator, name='MockCalculator')

    def multiply_proxy(n):
        '''Multiply by 2*multiplier instead of multiplier so we can see the
        difference.
        '''
        return 2 * multiplier * n
    mock.multiply = multiply_proxy

    return mock

def increment_mock(n):
    '''Increment by 2 instead of 1 so we can see the difference.'''
    return n + 2

def decrement_mock(n):
    '''Decrement by 2 instead of 1 so we can see the difference.'''
    return n - 2
```

And now for the good part.  Patch `increment()` and `decrement()` to replace them with their mocks:

```
import unittest
from mock import patch
import machines

@patch('machines.increment', increment_mock)
@patch('machines.decrement', decrement_mock)
class TestMachine(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_mult(self):
        '''The bound method of Calculator is replaced with MockCalculator'''
        machine = machines.Machine(MockCalculator(3))
        self.assertEqual(machine.mult(3), 18)

    def test_incr(self):
        '''increment() is replaced with increment_mock()'''
        machine = machines.Machine(MockCalculator(3))
        self.assertEqual(machine.incr(3), 5)

    def test_decr(self):
        '''decrement() is replaced with decrement_mock()'''
        machine = machines.Machine(MockCalculator(3))
        self.assertEqual(machine.decr(3), 1)
```

Comment: this is the correct answer. [on another question ]the static method vs module methods issue](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/112137/is-staticmethod-proliferation-a-code-smell) is discussed and the conclusion is that static methods are a code smell and an imitation of Java-style where module function definitions don't exist and static methods are the only substitute.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. `staticmethod` is a valid python construct and knowing how to mock those functions is valuable. "Do something else" isn't the right answer especially considering you can mock staticmethods.

Comment: Read this and realized I too was overusing static method when I should have been using module functions. Even though this seems to be off topic for the question, it really helped me,  Thanks.

Comment: ... what Java devs have anything to do with over use of static methods in Python? decent Java devs all know not to overuse static method because it is difficult to test. I personally mostly use it for useful simple logic code which gets reuse a lot of time, and then you could group them into some utils, helpers classes. I rarely see that I need to mock the static code because it should be simple and tested on their logic. All the class call the static code, need to test their output before and after the call instead of mock the static code itself.

Comment: I know this is old but static methods are not a "code smell" (a phrase I abhor, sorry) when they either return an instance or take an instance so please be specific so that junior programmers don't get led astray.

Answer (score 14):

You were patching the wrong object. You must patch the `Calculator` from the `Machine` class, not the general `Calculator` class. Read about it [here](http://alexmarandon.com/articles/python_mock_gotchas/).

```
from mock import patch
import unittest

from calculator import Calculator
from machine import Machine


class TestMachine(unittest.TestCase):
    def my_mocked_mult(self, multiplier):
        return 2 * multiplier * 3
    def test_bound(self):
        '''The bound methods of Calculator are replaced with MockCalculator'''
        machine = Machine(Calculator(3))
        with patch.object(machine, "mult") as mocked_mult:
            mocked_mult.side_effect = self.my_mocked_mult
            self.assertEqual(machine.mult(3), 18)
            self.assertEqual(machine.incr_bound(3), 5)
            self.assertEqual(machine.decr_bound(3), 1)

    def test_unbound(self):
        '''Machine.incr_unbound() and Machine.decr_unbound() are still using
        Calculator.increment() and Calculator.decrement(n), which is wrong.
        '''
        machine = Machine(Calculator(3))
        self.assertEqual(machine.incr_unbound(3), 4)    # I wish this was 5
        self.assertEqual(machine.decr_unbound(3), 2)    # I wish this was 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I am testing class Machine, so it is not satisfactory to patch methods like Machine.mult().  Besides, the mock MockComputer.multiplier() works fine.  My question was about mocking or patching static and class methods Computer.increment() and Computer.decrement().

Answer (score 4):

One way to do it is

```
def test_increment(mocker):
    mocker.patch.object(Calculator, attribute='increment', return_value=10)
    ...actual test code...
```

Comment: "`mocker`"??? You have to explain what this is! I googled and assume it is coming from "pytest-mock", which I installed. I did a line like yours and it failed in exactly the same way as a `mock` context manager failed. Then I tried `mocker.patch`, followed by a string, in my case "app.App.exit" (subclass of `QApplication`). It worked. Note to others: this is NOT a context manager: there is no colon at the end and the next line is not indented. Useful bit of magic, so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I just did something that could be translated to your case like this:

```
class Calculator_Mock(object):
    def __init__(self, multiplier):
        ... # add whatever you need here

    def multiply(self, n):
        ... # add whatever you need here

    @classmethod
    def increment(self, n):
        ... # add whatever you need here
```

Then, in your test, something as simple as this:

```
class TestCalculator(TestCase):

    def test_increment_or_whatever(self):
        with patch.object(Calculator,
                          "increment",
                          return_value=Calculator_Mock.increment()) as increment_mock:
        ... # call whatever your calls Calculator.increment, the mock should run instead the Calculator.increment
```

Comment: This works well.  Py3 Docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.return_value